How to add tab automatically to std::map initial list with .clang-foramt
I hope
std::map<MyEnum, std::string> imageEditArgsTypeJsonMap = {
        {MyEnum::Key,               "Value"},
        {MyEnum::ShortKey,          "ShortValue"},
        {MyEnum::LongLongLongKey,   "LongLongLongValue"},
}

But now
std::map<MyEnum, std::string> imageEditArgsTypeJsonMap = {
        {MyEnum::Key, "Value"},
        {MyEnum::ShortKey, "ShortValue"},
        {MyEnum::LongLongLongKey, "LongLongLongValye"},
}

What clang-format option should I set?

This format AlignArrayOfStructures seems to be doing what you want. https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#alignarrayofstructures
